# Generating dynamic excel from phpspreadsheet which is basically analysis data

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have 3 tables data named survey, survey_questions and survey_answers.
where questions and answers are in the form of json data type where each question and answer have unique option ids.

Now, I have to write this data into excel in the following format(for more details pls click the links):

first row will have all questions along with its options
from second row, all the answer records should be populated.

Note:There are different question types in the survey like ranking,arrays,check box,radio etc...

Links for sample data:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TVc16HSlLq_Di-YmRTC_RPBBLC1tpbQQ
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w2VXnVYVZONo2YUdn_Vy_GOzdtjbWh4j
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1URIA0X5mYTxXItLKf3vswPqHxL45szIZ/view?usp=sharing

output of generated excel:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BaM74WX6u74ZsKoDK45gJrbbBJ9Wm_Gr

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a minimal code ?

Comment: I have solved this problem by doing some array processing before inserting data into excel itself.Basically, I formed required data in array and in for loop, appended html data using the data and then generated excel using phpspreadsheet

Comment: You can answer your own question if you think it would help others.